# retrofit : deal with property that can be either empty string or an array

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit2 and I have been asked to consume the following json:

> { "status":"success",
>       payload{
>         "prop1": 1234,
>         "prop2": ""    } }

The problem is that prop2 can be either an empty string or an array of objects. ( Empty array is not an option for them)

I don't remember  Retrofit having a mechanism to deal with with this sort of type inconsistency. I'm looking for a recipe to maybe receive this property as some kind of generic Object any maybe use GSon to parse it later or some other alternative way to make it work.

Comment: You could always make the parse type an `com.google.gson.JsonObject`. Then you can then check yourself if prop2 is a `String` or an `JsonArray`

Comment: but how do I do this check if the property is nested inside other properties? Any links where I can find out? I only know how to check values with Gson by passing a class to convert the json to, but in this case I cannot pass it a class

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to check if prop2 is either an array or an empty string

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson("{ \"status\":\"success\", \"payload\": { \"prop1\": 1234, \"prop2\": \"\" } }", JsonObject.class);
JsonObject payload = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("payload");
JsonElement jsonElement = payload.get("prop2");
if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
    // value of prop2 is an array
} else if (jsonElement.isJsonPrimitive()) {
    JsonPrimitive jsonPrimitive = jsonElement.getAsJsonPrimitive();
    if (jsonPrimitive.isString() && "".equals(jsonPrimitive.getAsString())) {
        // value of prop2 is an empty String
    }
}
```